# How can I create a new table of data in Power BI from a different query that updates daily?

Tags: sql, automation, append, powerbi, refresh

I have a SQL execute function generating a simple table on Power BI.  This table updates when there is a refresh with the latest data, which is good.  I was wondering if there was a way to create a new table in power BI that is the historical data from the SQL query?  The idea would be the original query updates at a set time everyday, and then that data gets copied and appended to a second table with a timestamp so over time I will have historical data of the original executed SQL function.  Is this possible, and is there a way to automate it so I don't have to manually append data every day?

Answer (score 2):

Power BI is not intended to be a database for you to store historical data. There *might* be some unstable and/or ugly workarounds to do what you're suggesting in Power BI but it's much better to use the proper tool for the job. Save your historical data in the database and connect Power BI to that.

Comment: What would you recommend as a better database for holding records created the instant it is asked for in an automatic fashion?

Comment: Probably a SQL table with a trigger for a stored procedure or something similar, but that's outside my area of expertise.