# Appending Data from CSV File on Web to Table in Microsoft Power BI

Tags: csv, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

There is a CSV data source online that publishes the latest data on COVID-19 cases in Austria.

https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/2809273e-d0bc-4eb3-a7d3-d01ef2168809

The CSV file consists of one row with the latest number (cases, recovered, hospitalized, deaths, etc). I would like to take the data each time that the CSV file is updated, and add the new data to a new row in a table so that I have a complete set of data. Alternatively, is there a way for me to grab all the data from the source (not just a one row latest update)? From the website, it appears they only make the latest row available. The data is updated approximately 2-3 times a day.

I have searched extensively online and cannot seem to find an answer. I have set up the CSV file as a data source. I also copied and pasted the data into a new query, which can serve as my complete data source. So I have two tables (AllgemeinDaten and Old Data).

I create a new query appending the source (AllgemeinDaten) with Old Data, but it doesn't create a new row keeping the old data from AllgemeinDaten and the new changed data from AllgemeinDaten.

Comment: Power BI is not a database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948771 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347703

Comment: If you have O365, use Power Automate (was Flow) to get the latest data and save it to onedrive/blob storage, every Nth hours. Use load from folder in Power BI to load the csv files into Power BI.